# Unable to detect second chance exception?

Tags: c, windows, debugging

I am trying to write a small app that debugs another process by its ID and monitors the app until it crashes.
For now I've written a small code, most of it is from the MS example for writing a debugger.

My target application never passes the if(!de.u.Exception.dwFirstChance), even after the target has crashed.

I am able to see the exceptions coming if I put a bp on if(!de.u.Exception.dwFirstChance), but no exception meets the condition.

P.S : Too many edits :/

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.foundation.diagnostics.h>
#include <debugapi.h>

#include <ntstatus.h>



        DEBUG_EVENT de;

    int _tmain(int pid)
    {

        DebugActiveProcess( pid);
        while (true)
        {

        int a;
        if (WaitForDebugEvent (&de, (DWORD)1000))
        {

          if (de.dwDebugEventCode == EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT)
                {

                    if(!de.u.Exception.dwFirstChance)
                        int excep = de.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode;




                }



          }

         ContinueDebugEvent (   de.dwProcessId,
                                de.dwThreadId,
                                DBG_CONTINUE);

        }


    }
```

Comment: "Crashes" are unhandled exceptions in Windows.  You get the EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT event.  Twice, the second time EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO.dwFirstChance will be 0.

Comment: Thanks to user28644740 I figured this one out! I've modified the code accordingly, but my code does not pass the condition of (!dwFirstChanceException), even after I crash the target.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't assume that the app doesn't handle the exception itself.  Try this with a little "Hello crash" app first, simply dereference a null pointer.

Comment: I have a reliable means to crash the APP. It crashes and WER launches, so is it not safe to assume that the exception remained unhandled?
Procdump is able to detect the crash, so does windbg and olly.
still, I can try what you said. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you're doing it wrong.  On the top of the wrong-list is certainly the hard-coded PID and the unreasonably short timeout.

Comment: @HansPassant, my PID is hardcoded just for convenience. I launch the target first, note down the PID in application, then build my application. Is there some way to pass parameters in VS? I just use this to pass the parameters in VS for easy debugging. Eventually I will commend out that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article ["Writing a Plug-in for Sysinternals ProcDump v4.0"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580738.aspx) indicates in the pseudo-code that the dump of a monitored process is generated *when* (and only when) a "Second Chance Exception" occurs.

```
// (extract altered for brevity)
Else "Second Chance Exception"
    WriteDump(..)
    Done = True
```

And ["Writing a basic Windows debugger"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger) indicates that [EXCEPTION_DEBUGINFO.dwFirstChance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with a guard for STATUS_BREAKPOINT/EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT can be used to detect this case.

["First and second chance exception handling" (KB105676)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675) explains the difference between the exception chance types:

> However, if the application is being debugged, *the debugger sees all [first chance] exceptions before the program does*. This is the distinction between the first and second chance exception: the debugger gets the first chance to see the exception (hence the name).

It is these First Chance Exceptions ("managed" or not) which are being detected, but they are almost all recoverable - i.e. they are caught by the application/run-time code and dealt with appropriately.

> If the debugger allows the program execution to continue and does not handle the exception, the program will see the exception as usual. *If the program does not handle the exception, the debugger gets a second chance to see the exception.* In this latter case, *the program normally would crash if the debugger were not present.*

Thus, procdump likely generates the dump for a second chance exception with the assumption that any process-fatal exception will not be suppressed (by another debugger, as the program gave up its chance).

(EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT occurs *after* the process is terminated and is thus too late to generate an appropriate dump, although it does signal to end monitoring.)

---

YMMV: All information/observations comes from the articles and resources listed, without actual experience in usage of such techniques.

Comment: I modified the code to check for the dwFirstChance,
Didn't gain anything. The exception is not detected. Will try to figure this one, thanks!. Here is the code I modified.
int _tmain(int pid)
{
 pid = 7104;
 DebugActiveProcess( pid);
 while (true)
 {

 int a;
 if (WaitForDebugEvent (&de, (DWORD)1000))
 {
  
   if (de.dwDebugEventCode == EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT)
            {

    if(!de.u.Exception.dwFirstChance)
     int excep = de.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode;
    }blah blah..

Comment: I did not put any guard, I was just looking for any exception that goes unhandled. I got the guard part, but right now I just wanted to observe an exception that is thrown to me after the program fails to handle it. I did not find any such exception even after I crashed my target with some input. I put a BP after my if(!de.u.Exception.dwFirstChance). I would be happy if even EXCEPTION_BP comes to me as a fatal exception.

Comment: @user28644740, yes I have this after my if block. ContinueDebugEvent( de.dwProcessId, de.dwThreadId,DBG_CONTINUE);
Which is why I can continue it. I am seeing exception in the IF statement, but none of them pass the condition I set. Adding the code till now to the question.
I am seeing a whole lot of exceptions, but none of them pass the condition (!dwFirstChance). Which is what I am trying to figure.

Comment: (From the OP) EDIT From Question Author :- Thanks for the answer, it really helped me out, FYI, the error I am experiencing is because i've hardcoded DBG_CONTINUE in ContinueDebugEvent. Rather than this, at firstchance exception, We should set it to DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED. This will leave the exception to be handled by the application, which it should in all cases but the unhandled once, which will come back to us as SecondChanceException. Writing this down in your answer for others to read.

Comment: @lel Feel free to ahead and alter/correct/detail answers as appropriate, but keep the thanks/etc to comments - else they'll likely be rejected edits xD

Answer (score 0):

There is a previous question/answer about the single step exception: [What is a single step exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539380/what-is-a-single-step-exception)

Every exception you enumerated will crash your application if unhandled.  There is a lot of information on the web about each.

Simple newbie advice: it is very unlikely that you are the first person ever to encounter a problem or wonder what something means.  Google is a more appropriate tool for things like this.  Google first, StackExchange if you can't find the answer.

Comment: Buffer overflow = you wrote past the end of your array/allocated memory.
Access violation = usually trying to use a null pointer.

Comment: Then why did you ask?